# How to use an image JavaScript File Object as an image src (<img />)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an image file in the form of a JavaScript [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object. I was to add it to an <img> tag so I can render it in my React project. This is going to be used in my Client side code so I do not want it to be downloaded. I was looking at a few similar (but not exact) questions and they all use a FileReader but I cannot seem to get it to work. I keep getting an `ImagePreview.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`. My object is a File object which is a type of Blob according to the Mozilla document. Maybe I am confused? Could someone point me in the right direction? This is what the object looks like when I print it to the console:

```
File {name: 'gopher1.png', lastModified: 1633647754682, lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 07 2021 18:02:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 34156, …}
lastModified: 1633647754682
lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 07 2021 18:02:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) {}
name: "gopher1.png"
size: 34156
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
```

Comment: Can you share a code sandbox with a demo of what you have so far in terms of code?

Comment: You are certainly not passing what you think to this method, but note that you should not use a FileReader here anyway. To render the image from the Blob, [create a blob URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

Comment: @Kaiido this is exactly what I am looking for! Had to do a few tweaks but it works, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you do

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

then use url as a src